# Add custom spacing or gaps between bars in barplot ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to add custom spacing between bars in a barplot using ggplot function `geom_col()`?

I want to recreate something like this but in ggplot:

```
x <- c(2, 4, 7, 5)
barplot(x, space = c(0, 2, 1, 3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
data.frame(y=c(2, 4, 7, 5), x=cumsum(c(0, 2, 1, 3))) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous()
```

[image: ggplot with spaced columns]